# Network wide flag summary

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, flag-history

Since I've become active on the Smoke Detector Project, I accumulated over 85 accounts on various stack exchange sites, and all but three are there mainly to flag spam.

I've recently been searching for a way to view a summary of my network-wide flags, with things like helpful/declined and status, like a per-site flag summary.

Does this already exist (if so where can I find it)?

Or could SE maybe provide something like that?

Or maybe could even an userscript provide something like that?